# Database/Reference on optimal conditions for plant growth in greenhouses

Tags: open-data, database

We are a group of computer science students currently working on a university project to create a (almost) self-sufficient greenhouse.

The hardware and software aspects being almost finished, we would now want to begin testing. To do so, given that we are very far from being specialists in the matter, we are looking for a database or a reference book about optimal conditions for fruit/vegetable growth in a small format greenhouse.

The project being mainly to show the software and hardware aspects of it, the aim isn't for long-term growth or a full-fledged production. We are looking to grow, for example, tomatoes and/or strawberries long enough to show that the process works in theory.

Sorry for the weird question. Thanks in advance!

PS: I did post this question on the Biology SE, which sent me to the Gardening SE, which found the question to be off-topic. Hoping to be a bit more lucky here.

Comment: I was very close to voting to close this question because it indicates very little prior research. Have you or your team conducted a literature search? By doing a simple on-line search I found some interesting information. I'm also intrigued by the fact that most of the hardware & software aspects of the project are almost finished. What parameters will the system be measuring? If you don't know about the optimal growing conditions for plants prior to establishing the hardware  & software you may have under or over designed the system.

Comment: You might look into permaculture design.

Comment: @Fred we are using several sensors to check the environment in the greenhouse (temperature, luminosity, ground/air humidity, etc). We have tested many aspects of it and it works quite ok for now. The whole thing is controlled using a control algorithm that tries to keep the environment to certain values that we feed to it. So, it works (theoretically of course) for any reasonable value that we set it to. So what we are looking for is **what** that reasonable value would be for plant A or plant B. And I have to admit we are struggling to find what you found as easily as you say.

Comment: @user4624937 Thank you, will look into it.

Comment: Do you have a plan for dealing with pests and disease? In a greenhouse these problems can quickly get out of control.